# German characters are not displaying properly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am facing a problem on displaying characters :

Ex : My word is : `Üniversäl`
but it is displayed as : `√únivers√§l` when I print this word.

How can I resolve this issue ?

As shown here It display proper word in hint : 
[image: It display proper word in hint]
but when I print the string str1 its printing `√únivers√§l`

Comment: Where and how are you displaying it?

Comment: `Üniversäl` is not a German word :-)

Comment: Google translate detects it as Turkish.

Comment: Ok but my problem is with german characters. they are not displaying properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "print the string"? It's likely your output console is unable to display/handle unicode.

Comment: @NishantTyagi: I understand, that was not a serious comment. - But how do you print the `str1` variable?

Comment: I mean when I print this using NSLog in console it display wrong.

Comment: @NishantTyagi: Do you mean the debugger console in Xcode, or output to  a Terminal console?

Comment: I am talking about debugger console in XCode

Comment: @MartinR do you have any idea for resolving this issue ?

Comment: Can't say nothing without seeing your's 'print the string'.

Comment: @NishantTyagi: No, because I do not understand the problem yet. You said something about a label below. Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: It will be fine on `UILabel` or anything. Don't trust the `NSLog`.

Comment: @NishantTyagi: All this is very strange (and nobody except you can reproduce the problem :-) Please show the output of `NSLog(@"str1=%@", [str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])`, so that we can check if the string has correct contents or not.

Comment: I got this output `str1=<e2889ac3 ba6e6976 657273e2 889ac2a7 6c>`

Comment: @NishantTyagi: OK. That means that `str1` already has the wrong contents (and the problem is not the display!). `e2 88 9a` is UTF-8 for `√`, and `c3 ba` is UTF-8 for `ú`. So this is already wrong in the string. The problem must be where you assign a value to the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with [metal umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut)?

It depends on the encoding of the output channel you are using.

For example:

```
    NSString *universal = @"Üniversäl";

    NSLog(@"Üniversal: %@", universal);

    printf("%s\n", [universal cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]);
    printf("%s\n", [universal cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);
    printf("%s\n", [universal cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

"prints" the string to the terminal in three different encodings. Does one of them look right to you?

Comment: Thanks dude. `[universal cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing your encoding to something more [UTF8-ish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

```
NSString *otherString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:"Üniversäl" encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",otherString); // outputs √únivers√§l

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:"Üniversäl" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",string);  // outputs Üniversäl
```

Comment: I used this as : `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[str1 UTF8String]];` but its still printing : **√únivers√§l**

Comment: @0x7fffffff I believe, this cannot work (reliable). I could be wrong, but I think the default encoding in Objective-C source files in Xcode is UTF-8. Furthermore, the compiler is not required to "understand" a "ü" in a C-string literal. The reliable way for initializing an Objective-C string literal is using C++ or Objective-C string literals, like @"Ü".

Comment: @Nishant Try this - NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:str1]; NSlog(@"string: %@", string);

Comment: @SamBudda its wrong. str1 is NSString so can not pass it this way directly as UTF8String.

Comment: @0x7fffffff how can I display these characters as I need to display them this way.

Comment: To check whether Xcode's console has issues (there were a few in Xcode 4.0 up to 4.3), just run the program in Terminal. NSLog should go to the error console. (well, a simple console program as test)

Comment: No I am displaying the word in cell.textLabel.text so when I check it in my database it is proper but when set in cell textlabel it changes as I described.

Comment: @NishantTyagi: Then please show the code how you assign the string to the label.

Comment: I am getting the word from the array and assigning in cell label as:  `cell.textLabel.text = [[sectionedgroupArr objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"groupname"];`

Comment: @NishantTyagi: So what is wrong: The text displayed in the label, or the NSLog output, or both?

Comment: both. I am getting same output in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but I wanted to add a screenshot to my comment.

I dragged and dropped a UILabel to my storyboard and attached it to label1. Every thing looks fine to me. I am using Xcode 4.6 with iOS 6. Tell me if I missed something?

```
@interface v1ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

@end

@implementation v1ViewController
@synthesize label1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Üniversäl", nil];

   NSString *str2 = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
   //NSLog(@"str2: %s",[str2 UTF8String]);  // outputs √únivers√§l
   NSLog(@"str2: %@",str2);  // outputs Üniversäl
   label1.text = str2;

}
```

[image]

Comment: this is diffrent thing as you are directly passing the string which you need to log. I also get proper word if I pass this way at my end.

Comment: @NishantTyagi look at my modified answer. I still get the same results. I guess the only difference is how are you storing and retrieving your sectiongrouparry?